# Can I run a PHP script that runs a C script which then creates a file?

Tags: php, c, system

So when loading a page on a website I run a C script that creates some files.

Everything works perfectly on their own but put together I get a segmentation fault.

```
system('./cScript /var/www/html/someFile.txt', $returnValue);
```

The C script takes that parameter and creates another file based on it:

```
FILE *f;  
f = fopen ('/var/www/html/someFile.bak', "w");  
fprintf (f, "%s", "some content goes here");  
fclose (f);
```

It works if I run the C script on it's own
It works if I run `PHP -a` and `system('./cScript /var/www/html/someFile.txt', $returnValue);`

But it doesn't work if I run it via the browser. The C script does run though, so I get some response from it on the browser it's just the creating file part that doesn't work.

Could it be some kind of permission I'm not aware of? or a path related issue?

Comment: Does the user that runs the web server have read/write permissions on the directory? Try logging on as that user and then run your script!

Comment: Well php is currently running as root

Comment: probably a  permissions error. you should ALWAYS check return values from calls involving external resources, e.g. opening a file. never ever assume success. your C code assumes nothing could ever go wrong, which is very bad coding practice. and no, php wouldn't be running as root, unless you're running your webserver as root (very very very bad practice). your webserver STARTS up as root, but should be dropping root privs and running as a different user, e.g. www-data.

Comment: 'c program' my lord @iharob

Answer (score 1):

So yeah it was a permission problem, PHP was running as www-data and it didn't have write permission so it was throwing an error that I wasn't catching with my lets-keep-it-extremelly-simple-to-start-with code.

Can be fixed by granting permission to www-data:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www/html
```

That is not very secure though and bad practice so ideally don't do this.
But if you have to then might as well create some directory specifically designed to store these files high up in the hierarchy.